# Should I check the AsyncStorage token value against a key in expo react native?

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I'm new to react native and I'm trying to build a authentication system for my app using the expo cli. I think I understand it generally now, but all of the articles I've read seem to say you should check if a user token exists in AsyncStorage and if it does then take user to the Home/Account page and skip the login, but the token is never compared with a special key or anything. Here is an example of the code it says to return in the articles...

```
return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {state.userToken == null ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
```

I'm building an app with a monthly membership fee and so do I need to check if the userToken exists and if it does send it to the backend to be validated and then return the user data like in the code below, as this is what I did for the website version that used react, and if the userToken doesn't exist then I just send them to the login page?

```
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false)
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null)

const handleUserToken = () => {
  // fetch call that sends userToken to be validated and returns {userData, isAuthenticated}
  setSomeState(userData)

  return isAuthenticated
}

state.userToken == setIsAuthenticated(false) ? setIsAuthenticated(handleUserToken())

return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {!state.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

Hope this example makes sense, I would pass the userData down to the components using 'useContext' as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to be more restrictive you should check. Non-rooted device can't read or write data stored by AsyncStorage, but rooted devices can. Check this https://medium.com/dev-genius/security-in-react-native-applications-asyncstorage-4a619d923638

But validating user token with server increases the app opening dealy. Instead, I recommend using other encrypted storage techniques.

Comment: Thanks, but if I need to get the most up to date user data anyway, am I not just better off comparing it in the database and returning the result along with the user data. I know there's things like secure store, but this wouldn't give me the user data anyway

Comment: In that case, I think it is ok to validate with the server. But if you are storing same user  token per user for all the devices, then there might be a security issue because rooted devices can read that user token, so make sure you store your tokens securely.

Comment: The user tokens will be random generated and unique to each user and then they'll be validated on the backend with a key

Comment: Yeah, but also enure uniqueness per user per device